# Joda Time - Convert a String into a DateTime with a particular timezone and in a particular format

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to convert a String Date into a DateTime object for a particular timezone and in a particular format. How can I do it ?

String Date can be in any format used in the world. Example MM-DD-YYYY, YYYY-MM-DD, MM/DD/YY
, MM/DD/YYYY etc. TimeZone can be any legal timezone specified by the user.

Example - convert YYYY-MM-DD into MM/DD/YY for the Pacific Timezone.

Comment: Care to give 'particular' String, timezone and format?

Comment: There are some examples at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) to build a formatter that is able to parse/format multiple `DateTimeFormat`s, and set the resulting `DateTimeFormatter` to use a specified `DateTimeZone`:

```
DateTimeParser[] parsers = { 
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM-dd-yyyy").getParser(),
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").getParser(),
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy").getParser(),
  DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd").getParser()
};

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .append(null, parsers)
  .toFormatter()
  .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);

DateTime dttm1 = formatter.parseDateTime("01-31-2012");
DateTime dttm2 = formatter.parseDateTime("01/31/2012");
DateTime dttm3 = formatter.parseDateTime("2012-01-31");
```

To format a given `DateTime` you can just use `dttm1.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"))`.

Comment: I added some lines and got an output.

    System.out.println(dttm1);
    System.out.println(dttm2);
    System.out.println(dttm3);

Output is - 

    2012-01-31T00:00:00.000Z
    2012-01-31T00:00:00.000Z
    2012-01-31T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: I am not able to understand the code properly. Does this convert all of the 4 formats in parsers to "YYYY-MM-DD" + 0s format ? How can I remove all those zeros ?

Comment: @davidblaine: That's because you have a `DateTime` object. If you just want a string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, call `dttm1.toString("YYYY-MM-DD")`.